# Problem with adding Firebase Crashlytics to iOS Share Extension

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, share-extension

I'm trying to add Firebase to collect analytics events and crashes to iOS Share Extension. Everything works perfect in main app but not in Share Extension. I managed to find this way of initialization:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    // other code
}
```

`Analytics.logEvent` works perfectly, I can see events in firebase console, but crashes are not collected.

In addition, xcode organizer periodically collects the following crashes:

[image]

Who can tell what could be the reason and what to do to make Crashlytics collect crashes?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by adding this:

```
if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
}
```